# Updating from 12.04 to 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows-vista

I had issues updating to 13.04 from 12.04, so I went for a clean install of 13.04. the installation process went smoothly, and Ubuntu prompted me to restart in order to complete the installation. When I clicked on restart, instead of restarting, I got a black screen. after about 10 minutes, I shut it down, and booted up. When I was using 12.04, I could select Vista or Ubuntu. now, it automatically boots windows.

Comment: Your `Ubuntu 13.04` installed perfectly without any problem. Only problem is that you the entry of Ubuntu was not able to create in Boot record.. You can use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix your issue.. It will fix your Grub problem.. Give it a try. Reply if you need further help..

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that the GRUB entry in your MBR is no longer working. To work around this, you must use `boot-repair`. To do so:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open Terminal
2. Type `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Wait for it do finish. Do not close Terminal.
4. Type `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Wait for `boot-repair` to pop up. Do not close Terminal.
6. Choose the "Recommended Repair"
7. Do what you are told. Once `boot-repair` is done, you can restart your computer.
8. Profit!

Comment: Currently, I'm unable to even boot ubuntu unless I use the CD. There's no sign that Ubuntu even exists on my hard drive. If I try to install Ubuntu, I have to wipe my HD. I had 12.04 working earlier. Is there another way?